# Why does sudo need the loopback interface?

Tags: sudo, hostname

We were trying to install our software on an Ubuntu machine. To do so, we needed `root` privileges. Basically, all we needed to do was run a runnable jar like: `sudo java -jar runnableJar.jar`.
All such commands would return: `Unable to resolve host xxxxx`.

The `/etc/hosts` file had the incorrect `hostname` listed against the loopback interface which was causing this error. All commands which did not require `sudo` ran well.

I have been reading up on the loopback interface and my understanding is that it sets up localhost and is a virtual network interface. However, why does `sudo` need it at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the sudoers file permits the specifying of hostnames in the rules, `sudo` needs to know what the name of your Ubuntu machine is.

Because of this, `sudo` collects a list of all interfaces on your Ubuntu machine (loopback and "real").  See relevant section from `sudo` source code for interfaces.c, at the link below.

http://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/d8150a3fd577/interfaces.c